# Activating Matlab from Command line and from Launcher

Tags: command-line, unity, permissions, launcher, matlab

When I type `Matlab` (without sudo) on the command line for the shell, matlab properly opens.
Then, on the left pane in `Ubuntu 16.04`, I tell `Ubuntu` to lock `Matlab` to launcher.

However, when I try to activate it from the launcher, it shows the boot screen, and then closes without any error.

Since it works from shell without permissions, I guess it's not a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB, the `matlab-support` package "add[s] an entry to the launcher and some other features", therefore installing it may be the most straightforward solution. You can install it by running:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install matlab-support
```

Comment: Thanks! I followed the installation process, but the created launcher has the same issue.

Comment: Do you see any errors?